# The vector pass looks strange when viewed from the render layers node to the viewer node

Tags: compositing-nodes

[image]
Image 1 shows the vector pass of the render layers node directly checked by the viewer node. The image looks strange.

[image] 
In image 2, the vector pass is outputted to openEXR through the file output node and then reloaded into the image node in the blender and checked by the viewer node. The image looks perfect.

**Q1 : how to check vector pass correctly in render layers?**
**Q2 : Why is this difference between image 1 and image 2?**